# How to recover Chrome open tabs

Tags: browser, chrome-for-android, browser-history

I used to have the Chrome app with more or less 40 open tabs for some months. I opened it pretty often and it always restored all the tabs, until yesterday. I opened Chrome by mistake while I was having connection issues and it was not able to restore all my tabs. The next time I opened it, it only restored 5 tabs and the others seem to be gone. I tried searching for my tabs in Chrome history but I wasn't able to find them, instead I only see all the tabs opened in my other devices (PCs, Tablet, ecc.). I also tried to search for my tabs in the browsing history of my Google account, but I wasn't able to find them there neither: it seems that Chrome didn't load for real most of the tabs.
Is there a way to recover my open tabs? Does Chrome have a local history (opposed to the general history of the Google account which contains browsing history of all the devices used with that account)?

Comment: Sounds like you've tried everything that I have done before to resolve this issue.

One more thing to try if you haven't -- just taking a shot in the dark here -- is to close out all of the Chrome instances on all devices and then open Chrome back up on your phone -- maybe even restart the device -- then see if Google's servers sync up and with a little luck maybe the tab history will then display them for you.  Again... shot in the dark but thought it'd be worth a try.